# Is this a valid proof of the Boundedness Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity

Let $I = [a, b]$ be a closed, bounded interval. I want to prove that if $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $I$ then $f$ is bounded on $I$.

Proof: We prove by contradiction. Assume $f$ is unbounded on $I$. Since $f$ is continuous at $x=a$, then for any given $\epsilon_0 > 0$, $\exists \delta_0$ : if $|x-a| < \delta_0$ then $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon_0 \implies |f(x)| < |f(a)|+\epsilon_0 := M_0$. But since $f$ is unbounded $\exists x_0 \in I : |f(x_0)| > M_0$. Thus $x_0 >= a+ \delta_0.$ But we can find $\epsilon_1 > \epsilon_0$ such that $|f(x_1) - f(a)| < \epsilon_1$. Because $f$ is continuous, $\exists \delta_1$ : if $|x-a| < \delta_1$ then $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon_1 \implies |f(x)| < |f(a)|+\epsilon_1 := M_1$. Clearly $\delta_1 \geq \delta_0$. Continuing in this way we can construct a sequence $(x_n) = (a+\delta_n)$ which is monotonically increasing and bounded above by $b$ with $b$ as supremum for the sequence. Thus $(x_n)$ has a limit at $b$. The $M_n$ are also increasing which means $(|f(x_n)|)$ is increasing and unbounded so $f$ has no limit at $b$ and thus $f$ is not continuous, which contradicts our initial assumption.

Comment: You haven't proved that $(x_n)$ tends to $b$ or that $f(x_n)$ is unbounded.

Comment: $(x_n)$ tends to $b$ because each $x_n \in I$, increasing and bounded above by $b$. $f(x_n)$ is unbounded because $|f(x_n)|$ is unbounded

Comment: No. There are many increasing sequences in $I = [a, b]$ that do not tend to $b$. You haven't said anything about the quantities $\varepsilon_n$ or $M_n$ to guarantee that $|f(x_n)|$ is unbounded.

Comment: For $b$ to be a limit, you it needs to be the Least upper bound. Any bound greater than the least upper bound is an upper bound. The monotone convergence theorem only guarantees convergence for the l.u.b.

Comment: But the limit for $(x_n)$ is clearly $b$ because I can take $(x_n)$ arbitrarily close to $b$

Comment: But the limit for $(x_n)$ is clearly $b$ because I can take $(x_n)$ arbitrarily close to $b$. For any number $c$ lesser than $b$ let $\epsilon_c = c- a$. Then you can find an $x_K > c$ such that $|f(x_K) - f(a)| < \epsilon_c$

Comment: You haven't said how you achieve those properties in your proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your intuitive approach of starting from the continuity property at one end of the interval (point $a$) and arguing towards the other end (point $b$) in a sequential manner, then finding a contradiction with the unbounded property at some point in the way. However, you cannot "move forward" to the right end as you proposed. Incrementally choosing larger $\epsilon_{i+1} > \epsilon_i$ at each iteration $i$ does **not** imply having a monotonically increasing sequence $x_n = a + \delta_n$.

For instance, let us select an $\epsilon_0 >0$. Then you are right in saying that there exist a $\delta_0>0$ such that, if $|x-a|<\delta_0$ then $|f(x) - f(a)|<\epsilon_0$. If we now select another $\epsilon_1 > \epsilon_0$, there exist $\delta_1 := \delta_0$ such that, if $|x-a|<\delta_1 = \delta_0$ then $|f(x) - f(a)|<\epsilon_0 < \epsilon_1$. You can continue this argument iteratively for all $\epsilon_i$. In this case, the supremum (and limit) of the sequence $(x_n)_n$ becomes $a+\delta_0$, not necessarily $b$.